# How do I make a pop-up bubble/dropdown with a list of checkmarks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a website where I want to be able to click on a button and have a dropdown or a bubble. Something that looks like the drop from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/).

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Although I know that this is just a dropdown menu, I'd like mine to be able to have a list of checkmarks where you can tick some options on and off.

Does anyone know a tool or similar that I can use to create this?

Comment: Your image is a screenshot of your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, Accidentally copied something else in my clipboard. I added my original link now.

Comment: You mean like this?   http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/49/

Comment: Yes, thank you very much sir.

If you would post this as an answer I'll vote it as best answer :)
This helped me out, thank you!

Comment: I have a problem though, when I copy the code into my own project, nothing pops up when I click my link/button. Do you know what could cause this? I have remembered to import the url.

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery, as well as the Bootstrap files in your code.  It would be hard to give specifics as to why it doesn't work on your site without seeing the code itself...  it should work just as in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` with a class `drop down-menu` should be able to be replaced by about any element...  not necessary just a list.    However, to answer the question, you should be able to place any form elements you want in there, such as this...

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <form>
       <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
    </form>
    <form>
       <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And a demo here:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/49/)**